# Exclude UUID field from Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a UUID field in Django 1.6 imported from django-uuidfield v0.4.0. I can't change Django versions.

```
id = uuidfield.UIIDField()
```

And all is fine, except when attempting to view the model in the Admin, when this error is displayed:

> expected a character buffer object

The problem seems to be this line:

```
 return mark_safe(force_text(value).translate(_js_escapes))
```

from site-packages/django/utils/functional.py

I have tried to exclude this field from the Admin view by excluding it specifically

```
exclude=('id',)
```

and by including a different field explicitly, hoping it would only process that field and not the ID field (as the docs seem to indicate).

```
include = ('email',)
```

But the error persists. It seems as if the Admin site is examining the fields anyway, ignoring any settings in the Admin setup. I have also set 'editable=False' in the model definition with no effect for the id field.

I don't need to  manipulate or edit this field in any way from the admin screen, just hide it so it does not crash the admin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you are importing that from, but Django has included its own [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) since version 1.7. You should certainly be using that instead.

Comment: It looks like it's coming from django-uuidfield==0.4.0 and I won't be able to update to 1.7 for this work, which obviously would be ideal.

Comment: I don't actually care about the field nor it's value, I just want to exclude it from causing the Admin to crash. It would have been excluded anyway from the Admin setup as it's not necessary

Comment: FYI It's actually since 1.8, not 1.7